# Diameter of real projective space.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, projective-space

Consider the Reimannian metric on $S^{n}$ induced by the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Use it to define a Riemannian metric on $P^{n}$ and calculate its diameter.

**My attempt:**
I have used the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ acts freely, smoothly and properly on $S^{n}$ and hence, we get a Riemannian covering map $\pi: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}/ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. I want to calculate the diameter of $P_{n}$. I was thinking of using geodesics for this purpose. I think we can choose any one point of $P^{n}$ and calculate the maximum distance of points from our fixed point and use that $\pi$ is a local isometry. Am I thinking correctly? I haven't studied curvature yet so is there a way to calculate the diameter without using curvature?

Comment: Yes you're thinking correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I am unable to proceed...

Comment: Show that any geodesic lifts up to a geodesic in the sphere.

Comment: Then I guess we can look at the great circle and take the shortest path among the geodesics connecting the point x (say) to y or -y. And the maximum distance then possible is $\pi$/2. I hope this is correct.